# Meaning of “ни в зуб ногой - ни в жопу пальцем”

Tags: перевод, выражения, идиомы

What does the mean expression “ни в зуб ногой - ни в жопу пальцем” ?

Comment: http://gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_8187

Comment: Another trial of this user to enlighten people using abusive expressions. I would call it sabotage.

Answer (score 1):

It means "to not know a thing (about something), to be completely incapable (of doing something)".

Note that the expression in your question consists of two parts. Every single part has this meaning and can be used alone but the second part is vulgar.